# Providing EntityManager by an @ConversationScoped method

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, entitymanager, jboss-weld, conversation-scope

I tried to run the simple JEE6 application generated by maven archetype groupId: org.fluttercode.knappsack , artifactID: jee6-sandbox-archetype in JBoss7.
(went through this [turial](http://javathreads.de/2011/05/tutorial-mit-java-ee-6-unter-eclipse-helios-und-mit-maven-unterstuetzung-starten/), sorry, in German)

However, when calling the welcome JSF, I get the following error message:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalProductException: WELD-000053 Producers 
  cannot declare passivating scope and return a non-serializable class:  
  [method] @Produces @DataRepository @ConversationScoped 
  public org.rap.jee6project.bean.DataRepositoryProducer.getEntityManager()
org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.checkReturnValue(AbstractProducerBean.java:264)
org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:362)
org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:122)
```

Indeed, the DataRepositoyProducer class which is supposed to return an EntityManager instance, is defined an annotated as follws:

```
@Stateless
public class DataRepositoryProducer {


private EntityManager entityManager;

@Produces @DataRepository @ConversationScoped
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

}
```

If I use @RequestScoped, the application runs as promised. I wonder why other people who went through this tutorial didn't experience this problem? And how to fix it properly (using @RequestScoped means that the bean is recreated for each user request, right?, which I expect to be not very efficient)

The official JEE6 Tutorial says: "*Beans that use session, application, or conversation scope must be serializable, but beans that use request scope do not have to be serializable*" . However, that does not seem to be the problem here, since the server is not comlaining about the bean not serializable but the product of the producer bean.

Comment: It works when making the DataRepositoryProducer a stateful bean and annotating the whole class as @ConversationScoped. Don't know if I should be happy with this solution.

Maybe, the concept of a producer is not the best practice for container provided objects like EntityManager.

Answer (score 1):

It should be..

```
@Stateful
@ConversationScoped
public class ProducerCreator implements Serializable{
    @PersistenceConText
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    ....
}
```

and if you want to use the same entity context in of each conversation it should be

```
@PersistenceContex(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
```

finally, If you want to have service layer, should create stateful and inject to conversation bean

Comment: Thanks, that's the like the solution I mentioned in my comment. I wonder whether I should use a Producer for getting an EntityManager instance anyway having in mind that a stateful EJB is hurting scalability. Why not injecting it in a JEE5 way, by using @PersistenceContext directly instead of using a dedicated producer bean.

Comment: By default EntityManager is transaction scoped. I think, it's not make sense to change entityManager to conversation scoped. Let's see Seam Persistence Module http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/PersistenceModule, If you really want to produced EntityManager.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem running the demo on a jboss7.

Just remove @ConversationScoped  at getEntityManager() did the trick to me to let it deploy.

Even though there are some flaws:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;    
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606) 
org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
```

I don't know exactly, if it is related, but I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: `EntityManager` is not serializable, so it cannot be stored in `ConversationScope`